# loopback packets on an interface using C sockets

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am trying to loopback packets received on a network interface . So for every packet I receive in the `nf2` interface, I want to transmit the same through the `nf2` interface. I don't want to swap the address or nat.  I Below is the code that I obtained online, that aims to achieve my same objective.

I am able to receive the packets without an issue as long as I don't enable the transmit part. Once I add the transmit part  `write(sock,buffer,data_size)`, the design runs indefinitely. I have commented out the Tx section (between Tx-part Start and Tx-part Stop).

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
int saddr_size , data_size, daddr_size, bytes_sent;
struct sockaddr_ll saddr, daddr;
unsigned char *buffer=malloc(65535);
int n = 0;
int count = 0;  

// Opening the socket

int sock_raw = socket( AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_ALL)) ; //For receiving
int sock = socket( PF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_RAW) ;            //For sending

// Initializing the memory address and variables for the sockets
memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
saddr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
saddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
saddr.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex("nf2");

// Binding the socket to the address
if (bind(sock_raw, (struct sockaddr*) &saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0) {
    perror("bind failed\n");
    close(sock_raw);
}

// Initializing the memory address
memset(&daddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
daddr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
daddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
daddr.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex("nf2");

// Binding the socket to the address
if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &daddr, sizeof(daddr)) < 0) {
  perror("bind failed\n");
  close(sock);
}

struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "nf2");
if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0) {
    perror("bind to nf2");
    }

while(1)
//while((n = read(sock_raw, &saddr, sizeof(&saddr)-1)) > 0)
{
    saddr_size = sizeof (struct sockaddr);
    daddr_size = sizeof (struct sockaddr);
    //Receive a packet
    data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 ,(struct sockaddr *) &saddr , (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);

    if(data_size <0 )
    {
        printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else{
    printf("%d Received %d bytes\n", count, data_size);
    count++;

    // Tx part -starts
    // The following section runs indefinitely

    //Send the same packet out
    //bytes_sent=write(sock,buffer,data_size);
    //printf("Sent %d bytes\n",bytes_sent);
    // if (bytes_sent < 0) {
    //    perror("sendto");
    //    exit(1);
    // }

    // Tx part - ends  
    }
}
close(sock_raw);
return 0;
}
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Seems like to me it *should* run "indefinitely": you have a `while (1)` loop. What do you expect to happen? Contrast that with what is actually happening. See also [ask]

Comment: My question was that: if i send one packet into the interface (reception), I expect one packet to be transmitted out. But sadly, I don't see that happening. When I send 10 packets to the interface (from external device),  I notice that more than 10 packets are transmitted out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are receiving each packet you're sending, and then re-copying it again. IOW: responding to yourself.

Use the `sll_pkttype` in the `struct sockaddr_ll` to distinguish outgoing packets and just ignore them. You can do something like this inside your loop:

```
while (1) {
    saddr_size = sizeof (struct sockaddr_ll);
    //Receive a packet
    data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw, buffer, 65536, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, &saddr_size);

    if (saddr.sll_pkttype == PACKET_OUTGOING) {
        printf("Ignoring outgoing packet\n");
        continue;
    }
```

See `packet(7)` for a description of the packet types.